# Calling a bash script function from another bash script doesn't display my shell command

Tags: bash

I have 2 bash scripts, one calling another but depending on how I call it, it does or does not display my ls command.

**script2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
function test() {
    i=0
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        IFS=',' read -ra ITEM <<<"$line"
        printf "\n[${i}] ${ITEM}"
        ((i = i + 1))
    done <<<$(ls $1)

    printf "\nPress any other keys to abort.\n\n" 
    read -p "Please enter your selection: " ANSWER 
    echo $ANSWER
}
```

**script1a.sh WORKS**

```
#!/bin/bash
. ./scripts/bash/script2.sh
PARAM='-lag'
(test $PARAM)
```

Returns:

```
[0] total 5  
[1] drwxr-xr-x 1 1049089    0 Oct 29 09:10 .  
[2] drwxr-xr-x 1 1049089    0 Oct  9 23:11 ..  
[3] -rw-r--r-- 1 1049089   87 Jul  6 14:19 .eslintignore  
[4] -rw-r--r-- 1 1049089  449 Jul 10 13:56 .forceignore  
[5] drwxr-xr-x 1 1049089    0 Oct 29 09:11 .git  
Press any other keys to abort.  

Please enter your selection:
```

**script1b.sh FAILS**

```
#!/bin/bash
. ./scripts/bash/script2.sh
PARAM='-lag'
myanswer=$(test $PARAM)
```

Returns:
Please enter your selection:

Anyone knows why this odd behavior and how to get around it?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `$( )` in script1b.sh is capturing the output -- including the file listing -- from the `test` function; if you print `myanswer` afterward, you'll see it. BTW, naming a function `test` is dangerous, because `test` is a builtin command that other scripts may depend on. Also, the `()` around `test $PARAM` in script1a.sh is not doing anything useful (it forces the function to run in a subshell). Also, I recommend [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) for pointing out some other problems in your scripts, and I recommend against [parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Thank Gordon.  That was just a quick script to describe the issue but it's not my real script, hence the test and script naming.  Makes sense, the output is captured hence why the read is displayed and not the output.

Comment: All good advice from Gordon. Also you'll do well to read, review and take to heart the items on this page : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Search for "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" .Good luck.